# What is the expected convolution1d_1 to have shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently using a covolutional layer to train a neural, but seem to have some problems feeding the input and output dimensions to it..

The input consist of (x,2050) 
and the output is (x,13)
So for each row with 2050 columns should a array of 13 elements be created..

```
#Define 10 folds:
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
print "Splits"
cvscores_acc = []
cvscores_loss = []
hist = []
i = 0
train_set_data_vstacked_normalized_reshaped = np.reshape(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized,train_set_data_vstacked_normalized.shape+(1,))
train_set_output_vstacked_normalized_reshaped = np.reshape(train_set_output_vstacked_normalized,train_set_output_vstacked_normalized.shape+(1,))
for train, test in kfold.split(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized_reshaped):

    print "Model definition!"
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Convolution1D(13, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(2050,1)))

    print "Compiling"
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="RMSprop")
    print "Compile done! "

    print '\n'

    print "Train start"

    reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.01, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0.00000001)
    stop  = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    log=csv_logger = CSVLogger('training_'+str(i)+'.csv')


    hist_current = model.fit(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized_reshaped[train],
                                train_set_output_vstacked_normalized_reshaped[train],
                                shuffle=False,
                                validation_data=(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized_reshaped[test],train_set_output_vstacked_normalized_reshaped[test]),
                                validation_split=0.1,
                                nb_epoch=150,
                                verbose=1,
                                callbacks=[reduce_lr,log,stop])

    hist.append(hist_current)

    print()
    print model.summary()
    print "Model stored"
    model.save("Model"+str(i)+".h5")
    model.save_weights("Model"+str(i)+"_weights.h5")
    del model
    print "New Model:"
    i=i+1
```

I seem to have problems feeding in the data, i read somewhere that that the `Convolution1D` expected a 3d  as input, and output, which is why i reshape it to a 3d.. But for some reason isn't it still not fitting.

I am getting this error with the current code:

```
Exception: Error when checking model target: expected convolution1d_1 to have shape (None, 2050, 13) but got array with shape (221286, 13, 1)
```

Why am i not able to start a training session?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically - in your network you have:

- an input which constist of sequences of 1-dimensional feature vectors with length of 2050 each.
- you are applying a set of 13 one-dimensional convolutional feature with `kernel_size = 3` what in a `same` border mode is producing sequences of 13-dimensional feature vectors with length of 2050 each.

This explains why Keras shows you that it's expecting a `(None, 2050, 13)` target shape.

There are several ways in order to make it works:

1. You could flatten your output from a convolutional layer by adding:

   ```
   from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense 
   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(13))
   ```

   and then also flatten your target by `train_set_output_vstacked_normalized_reshaped[train].reshape((221286, 13))`
2. By adding yet another convolutional layers combined with pooling and different border modes in order to obtain an output sequence with length 13. There are so many possibilites here that I will skip this part.

Please notice - that you are using here only activation functions. Whereas in a final `dense` layer it seems to be a good decision, in previous layers it's good to apply some non-linear activations (like `relu`) in order to make your network work better.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. there is one issue here with the reshaping.... The number of rows isn't the same, but the only the number of columns is consistent..

Comment: So please try padding sequences with 0s either at the beginning or at the end of the sequences.

Comment: I don't get why i should pad.  The number of rows for both input and output is the same for each set, but not the same overall...

Comment: Yes - but a model compiled needs to have every dimension of input specified at the compiling stage. So you also need to provide a length of a sequence.

Comment: The input data is an stft of an audio file, with each frame length being 25 ms and with an overlap of 10 ms. the audio file is sampled with 16000 hz.. 

Could the length of the frame, and the overlap somehow be beneficial.. meaning.. the window length can be defined as the 400 samples => 16000*0.25, and move the window 10 ms?...